# How to pass context or attributes in async.js waterfall?

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules, async.js

I would like to pass the current context or an attribute to functions in `async.waterfall`. How to:

1. pass `this`
2. an attribute (here `options` object)

This is what I already have:

```
var _authenticate = function (cbAsync) {
  var licenseId = options.licenseId; //options is undefined
};
module.exports = new Command('createOrga')
  .description('creates an organization')
  .option('-f, --file <file>', 'the structure file including full path')
  .action(function (options) {
      options.confirm = options.confirm || true; // No confirmation needed!
      options.organizationUUID = (uuid.v4()).toUpperCase();
      options.licenseId = (uuid.v4()).toUpperCase();
      //How to pass options object to _authenticate function????
      async.waterfall([ _authenticate ], function(err) {
        if ( err ) {
          console.warn('Error in creating new organization: ',err);
        }
        else {
          console.info('Successfully created new organization: ' + organizationUUID);
        }
      });
    }
  }
```

Comment: Which `this` you you want to pass?

Comment: The code posted above is only a subset. The question was if the context in `.action` e.g. `this` could be passed to `_authenticate`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [Function.prototype.bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to *pass*  variables.

```
async.waterfall([ _authenticate.bind(undefined, options)], function(err) {
    //your code
});
```

Because the bound variables are pass first, your callback then has to look like this:

```
var _authenticate = function (options, cbAsync) {
   var licenseId = options.licenseId; //options is undefined
};
```

Comment: So instead `undefined` as first attribute, `this` context could be provided, right?

Comment: @DoK Yes. What ever you pass instead of `undefined` will be the new `this` for your `_authenticate`, if you pass `this`  then it will be the same as the `this` within your `action` callback.